# When using the Favorite API to get all the favorites for the current user it returns as Http Response the Code: 302, Status: Moved Temporaly]?

Tags: api, lightning-experience, httprequest

I am using as reference this documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_favorites.htm

And it says that by doing an HTTP GET request to this url "/ui-api/favorites" it should retrieve "all of a user’s favorites.". But it seems it doesn't work.

I tried the following code in Execute Anonymous and received the error "HttpResponse[Status=Moved Temporarily, StatusCode=302]"

This is the code I tried in the sandbox, by the way I included some favorites to my user so it should retrieve something.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
string host = '{YOUR_SFDC_INSTANCE}.lightning.force.com';

String endpoint = 'https://' + host + '/ui-api/favorites';
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

system.debug(res);
```

Does anyone know if the Favorite API is still in use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to Classic and copy the host Url.

Also the endpoint is not
`String endpoint = 'https://' + host + '/ui-api/favorites';`

But

```
String endpoint = host +'/services/data/v45.0/ui-api/favorites';
```

where host is the base url in classic : eg: `myPranyorg.salesforce.com`

Comment: Thanks Pranay, now I got the "401: Unauthorized" error, I'll work on Oauth authentication now. Thanks for the help Pranay!

Comment: You have to set Authorization Header or used named credentials. As mentioned here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm

Comment: I did, Thanks Pranay!

Comment: @HanselP happy to help 